# Wordpress - apply_filters( 'the_content') not applied first time

Tags: html, wordpress, filter

I have a strange issue with this code:

```
foreach($map->markers as $marker)
{
    $description = apply_filters( 'the_content', $marker->description);
    echo '<div class="marker" data-icon="'.$marker->icon.'" data-lon="'.$marker->longitude.'" data-lat="'.$marker->latitude.'" data-name="'.$marker->name.'">'.$description.'</div>';
}
```

The $marker->description contain html content from TinyMCE editor and i apply the filter 'the_content' to have <p> and <br /> tags added.
It works for all my markers but not for the first: breakline aren't transformed in tags.

But if i put this line before my code it works:

`apply_filters( 'the_content', '');`

But i don't understand why i need to do a first call to the first and then the next works well?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I've got this issue too—did you happen to find any more info? As you mentioned, calling the_content on '' first solves the issue as a temporary bug fix. Odd.

Comment: I resolve this by using wpautop function instead of the filter 'the_content'. If still don't know why this bug appear...

Comment: Thanks for replying/confirming! That's how I fixed it too. Just bugs me not knowing the issue with the_content!